# Handling iOS runtime errors

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've been handed over (thrown in the deep end) responsibility  of an iOS application having had no previous experience with iOS programming. While I'm devouring iOS programming books I'm trying to run an app written in ObjectiveC using Xcode 7, SourceTree in OS X El Captain (10.11.1). In Xcode target is set to iOS 8.

The problem: I've pulled source code from GiT from a working version into my workspace but unfortunately I am encountering run time errors even before making any changes! The code breaks while attempting to load a view:

```
- (void)loadView
{
    [super loadView];
    UIView* view = self.view;
    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorForBackgroundLight];

    SEFSDashboardHeaderView* headerView = [[SEFSDashboardHeaderView alloc] init];
    self.headerView = headerView;
    [view addSubview:headerView];

    [headerView mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        UIView* topLayoutGuide = (UIView *)self.topLayoutGuide;
        make.left.equalTo(view);
        make.top.equalTo(topLayoutGuide.mas_bottom);
        make.right.equalTo(view);
        make.height.equalTo(@85);
    }];

    UITableView* tableView = self.tableView;
    tableView.rowHeight = 58;
    tableView.backgroundColor = view.backgroundColor;
    [view addSubview:tableView];
    self.tableView = tableView;

    [tableView mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.left.equalTo(view);
        make.right.equalTo(view);
        make.bottom.equalTo(view);
        make.top.equalTo(headerView.mas_bottom);
    }];
}
```

The offending line is:

```
make.top.equalTo(topLayoutGuide.mas_bottom);
```

In the debug area when I do a po on [topLayoutGuide.mas_bottom] I get:

*(lldb) po [topLayoutGuide mas_bottom]
error: warning: couldn't get cmd pointer (substituting NULL): no variable named '_cmd' found in this frame
Execution was interrupted, reason: Attempted to dereference an invalid ObjC Object or send it an unrecognized selector.
The process has been returned to the state before expression evaluation.
(lldb)*

My understanding is that property *mas_bottom* does not exist in topLayoutGuide object.

However there is a reference to *mas_bottom* in class massConstraintMaker.m with the following code:

```
- (MASConstraint *)addConstraintWithAttributes:(MASAttribute)attrs {
    MASAttribute anyAttribute = MASAttributeLeft | MASAttributeRight | MASAttributeTop | MASAttributeBottom | MASAttributeLeading | MASAttributeTrailing | MASAttributeWidth | MASAttributeHeight | MASAttributeCenterX | MASAttributeCenterY | MASAttributeBaseline;

    NSAssert((attrs & anyAttribute) != 0, @"You didn't pass any attribute to make.attributes(...)");

    NSMutableArray *attributes = [NSMutableArray array];

    if (attrs & MASAttributeLeft) [attributes addObject:self.view.mas_left];
    if (attrs & MASAttributeRight) [attributes addObject:self.view.mas_right];
    if (attrs & MASAttributeTop) [attributes addObject:self.view.mas_top];
    if (attrs & MASAttributeBottom) [attributes addObject:self.view.mas_bottom];
    if (attrs & MASAttributeLeading) [attributes addObject:self.view.mas_leading];
    if (attrs & MASAttributeTrailing) [attributes addObject:self.view.mas_trailing];
    if (attrs & MASAttributeWidth) [attributes addObject:self.view.mas_width];
    if (attrs & MASAttributeHeight) [attributes addObject:self.view.mas_height];
    if (attrs & MASAttributeCenterX) [attributes addObject:self.view.mas_centerX];
    if (attrs & MASAttributeCenterY) [attributes addObject:self.view.mas_centerY];
    if (attrs & MASAttributeBaseline) [attributes addObject:self.view.mas_baseline];

    NSMutableArray *children = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:attributes.count];

    for (MASViewAttribute *a in attributes) {
        [children addObject:[[MASViewConstraint alloc] initWithFirstViewAttribute:a]];
    }

MASCompositeConstraint *constraint = [[MASCompositeConstraint alloc] initWithChildren:children];
constraint.delegate = self;
[self.constraints addObject:constraint];
return constraint;
```

}

Is there a configuration setting problem? Should I start the application in a different way? I am currently opening the .xcworkspace file instead of .xcodeproj. Hopefully this is the right way.

If I could at least run the app without any runtime errors it would be a fantastic Christmas gift! Thank you.

Comment: will you please show us the error.? Just Copy error log from console.

Comment: @Dev_Tandel I've added the error log to the question.

Comment: You could start by tracing the value of `mas_bottom`, set a breakPoint every time it is called, maybe at some point it gets dealloc or something.

Comment: Using cocoa pods? Specified an explicit release version of the library? Know what specific version did used to work?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The problem was solved by removing XCODE 7.1 and installing XCODE 6.4.

Comment: While this may have prevented the error, it does not solve the problem and is definitely not the correct answer. Simply downgrading does not solve the issue at hand.